# How to use incremental solving with z3py

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am using the python API of the Z3 solver to search for optimized schedules. It works pretty well apart from that it sometimes is very slow even for small graphs (sometimes its very quick though). The reason for that is probably that the constraints of my scheduling problem are quite complex.
I am trying to speed things up and stumbled on some articles about incremental solving. 
As far I understood, you can use incremental solving to prune some of the search space by only applying parts of the constraints.

So my original code was looking like that:

```
for constraint in constraint_set:
    self._opt_solver.add(constraint)
self._opt_solver.minimize(some_objective)
self._opt_solver.check()
model = self._opt_solver.mode()
```

I changed it now to the following:

```
for constraint in constraint_set:
    self._opt_solver.push(constraint)
    self._opt_solver.check()
self._opt_solver.minimize(some_objective)
self._opt_solver.check()
model = self._opt_solver.mode()
```

I basically substituted the "add" command by the "push" command and added a check() after each push.

So first of all: is my general approach correct?
Furthermore, I get an exception which I can't get rid of:

> ```
> self._opt_solver.push(constraint) TypeError: push() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
> ```

Can anyone give me a hint, what I am doing wrong. Also is there maybe a z3py tutorial that explains (with some examples maybe) how to use incremental solving with the python api.

My last question is: Is that at all the right way of minimizing the execution time of the solver or is there a different/better way?

Answer (score 2):

The function `push` doesn't take an argument. It creates a "backtracking" point that you can `pop` to later on. See here: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_solver.html#abc4ae989afee7ad164844640537107d9

So, it seems `push` isn't really what you want/need here at all. You should simply add your constraints one-by-one and call `check`. However, I very much doubt checking after each addition is going to speed anything up significantly. The optimizing solver (as opposed to the regular one), in particular, usually solves everything from scratch. (See the relevant discussion here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1577)

Regarding incremental: The python API is automatically "incremental." Incremental simply means the ability to call the command `check()` multiple times, without the solver forgetting what it has seen before. (i.e., call `check`, assert more facts, call `check` again; the second `check` will take into account all the assertions from the very beginning.) You shouldn't make any assumptions regarding this will give you speed over calling `check` just once at the very end: It entirely depends on the heuristics and the decision procedures involved, which is dependent on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. So then my follow up question would be: If iterative solving wont help me with improving the speed of my optimization, what can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: The general (and admittedly not helpful) answer is that you need to "pick the right tactic," keeping in mind it may not exist. When you call `check`, the solver uses a portfolio of tactics, heuristics, etc. If you know which tactic works the best, then you should directly use that. But figuring that out is more of an art than science. Your best bet is to isolate a particularly slow case that you think should be easy to solve, make it self-contained, and ask for help here or directly at the z3 Github site. (You can search StackOverflow for "z3 tactic" and see a variety of similar questions!)