# SAT queries are slowing down in Z3-Python: what about incremental SAT?

Tags: z3, z3py, theorem-proving, sat

In Z3 (Python) my SAT queries inside a loop are slowing down, can I use incremental SAT to overcome this problem?

The problem is the following: I am performing a concrete SAT search inside a loop. On each iteration, I get a model (of course, **I store the negation** of the model in order not to explore the same model again). And also, if that model satisfies a certain property, then **I also add** a subquery of it and add **other restrictions** to the formula. And iterate again, **until UNSAT** (i.e. "no more models") is obtained.

I offer an orientative snapshot of the code:

```
  ...
  s = Solver()
  s.add(True)
  while  s.check() == sat: 
    s.check()
    m = s.model()
    phi = add_modelNegation(m)
    s.add(phi) #in order not to explore the same model again
    if holds_property(m): #if the model holds a property
       s = add_moreConstraints(s,m) #add other constrains to the formula
  ...
```

The question is that, as the formula that `s` has to solve gets greater, Z3 is starting to have more trouble to find those models. That is okay: **this should happen**, since finding a model is now more difficult because of the added restrictions. However, in my case, it is happening too much: the **computation speed** has been even **halved**; i.e. the time that the solver needs to find a new model is the double after some iterations.

Thus, I would like to implement some kind of **incremental solving** and wondered whether there are **native methods in Z3** to do so.

I have been reading about this in many pages (see, for instance, [How incremental solving works in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422018/how-incremental-solving-works-in-z3?rq=1)), but only found this response in [How to use incremental solving with z3py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272030/how-to-use-incremental-solving-with-z3py) interesting:

*The Python API is automatically "incremental". This simply means the ability to call the command `check()` multiple times, without the solver forgetting what it has seen before (i.e., call `check()`, assert more facts, call `check()` again; the second `check()` will take into account all the assertions from the very beginning).*

I am not sure I understand, thus I make a simple question: that the response mean that the **incremental SAT is indeed used in Z3**'s SAT? The point I think I am looking for **another *incrementality***; for example: if in the SAT iteration number 230 it is inevitable that a variable (say `b1`) is `true`, then that is a fact that will not change afterwards, you can set it to 1, simplify the formula and not re-reason anything to do with `b1`, because all models if any will have `b1`. **Is this incremental SAT of Z3 considering these kind of cases?**

In case not, how could I implement this?

I know there are some implementations in PySat or in MiniSat, but I would like to do it **in Z3**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with anything related to performance of z3 solving, there's no one size fits all. Each specific problem can benefit from different ideas.

*Incremental Solving* The term "incremental solving" has a very specific meaning in the SAT/SMT context. It means that you can continue to add assertions to the system after a call to `check`, without it forgetting the assertions you added before hand. This is what makes it incremental. Additionally, you can set jump-points; i.e., you can tell the solver to "forget" the assertions you put in after a certain point in your program, essentially moving through a stack of assertions. For details, see Section 3.9 of https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf, specifically the part where it talks about the "Assertion Stack."

And, as noted before, you don't have to do anything specific for z3 to be incremental. It is incremental by default, i.e., you can simply add new assertions after calling `check`, or use `push`/`pop` calls etc. (Compare this to, for instance, CVC4; which is by default not incremental. If you want to use CVC4 in incremental mode, you have to pass a specific command line argument.) The main reason for this is that incremental mode requires extra bookkeeping, which CVC4 isn't willing to pay for unless you explicitly ask it to do so. For z3, the developers decided to always make it incremental without any command line switches.

Regarding your particular question about what happens if `b1` is true: Well, if you somehow determined `b1` is always true, simply assert it. And the solver will automatically take advantage of this; nothing special needs to be done. Note that z3 learns a ton of lemmas as it works through your program such as these and adds them to its internal database anyhow. But if you have some external mechanism that lets you deduce a particular constraint, just go ahead and add it. (Of course, the soundness of this will be on you, not on z3; but that's a different question.)

One specific "trick" in speeding up enumerating "find me all-solutions" loops like you are doing is to do a divide-and-conquer approach, instead of the "add the negation of the previous model and iterate." In practice this can make a significant difference in performance. I think you should try this idea. It's explained here: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations) As you can see, the `all_smt` function defined at the end of that section takes specific advantage of incrementality (note the calls to `push`/`pop`) to speed up the model-search process, by carefully dividing the search space into disjoint segments, instead of doing a random-walk. Using this might give you the speed-up you need. But, again, as with anything performance specific, you'll need to tell us more about exactly what problem you are solving: None of these methods can avoid performance problems caused by modeling issues. (For instance, using integers to model booleans is one common pitfall.) See this answer for some generic advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661441/936310

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As for the last link, I think you definitively understand my problem: I want to avoid my solver being *innudated with new lemmas*.  Though, I still have a question: do you know what does *terms* mean in the function *block*? I will see whether this implementation helps me out and ask in a new question if not!

Comment: `terms` is simply the list of terms you want to find all assignments for. In a typical problem, this would be the list of variables that you care about. (Though you can also make them arbitrary terms for specific use cases.) That is, if you're looking for the values of the variables `x` and `y`, simply pass `[x, y]` as the argument; assuming `x, y = Ints('x y')` or similar was declared before.

Comment: That is what I thought, thus I passed `[x,y,z]` (I made a different example) but got the error `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable` :(

Comment: That should work, the problem must be elsewhere. Please post a minimal-example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Yep, should I do it here or in another question?

Comment: A separate question is better; to keep everything self-contained.

Comment: Perfect! Asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654594/in-z3-python-i-get-builtin-function-or-method-object-is-not-iterable-when-pe