# In Z3-Python, I get "builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" when performing model search

Tags: python, z3, z3py, theorem-proving, sat

I am exploring fast ways to perform SAT solving in Z3 (Python). To do so, I am trying to imitate the results of Chapter 5.1 of [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-blocking-evaluations).

The code I am using is the following:

```
def block_modelT(s, terms): #I used the name 'block_modelT' so as not to use 'block_model'
    m = s.model()
    s.add(Or([t != m.eval(t) for t in terms]))

def all_smt(s, terms):
    while sat == s.check():
       print(s.model())
       block_modelT(s, terms)
```

Thus, I execute it:

```
pip install z3-solver
from z3 import *

x, y, z = Bools('x y z')
vars = [x,y,z]

phi_0 = x #ignore that I call them phi: it is because I am used to do it like that for predicates (i.e. literals) of other theories: e.g., if x is Int, then phi_0 = (x>0)
phi_1 = y
phi_2 = z

phi = And(phi_0, Or(phi_1, phi_2))

all_smt(s, vars)
```

And get the following error:

```
      1 def block_modelT(s, terms):
      2     m = s.model()
----> 3     s.add(Or([t != m.eval(t) for t in terms]))

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Any help?

EDIT:

The problem has been solved so I finally try the next piece of code:

```
def all_smt(s, initial_terms):
    def block_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t != m.eval(t))
    def fix_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t == m.eval(t))
    def all_smt_rec(terms):
        if sat == s.check():
           m = s.model()
           yield m
           for i in range(len(terms)):
               s.push()
               block_term(s, m, terms[i])
               for j in range(i):
                   fix_term(s, m, terms[j])
               for m in all_smt_rec(terms[i:]):
                   yield m
               s.pop()   
    for m in all_smt_rec(list(initial_terms)):
        yield m
```

I execute it: `all_smt(s, varss) #has the same name`. And get a generator `<generator object all_smt at 0x7...` instead of a valid assignment (i.e. a model). How can obtain the correct answer `[z = False, y = True, x = True], [z = True, x = True]`? I tried both `print` and `return`.

Comment: I think I got it, **`vars` is a reserved word**!!!! I discovered it when Stack has coloured the word!

Comment: I don't think so.. `vars` isn't really reserved.

Comment: Changed it with `varss` and I have not received the error though..

Comment: See my answer below. `vars` works just fine for me. I'm using Python 3.9.1, maybe you have some other version. (Though I doubt it'd make a difference.)

Comment: Note that there's a bug in the implementation of `all_smt` in that paper. See this for the corrected version: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5765#issuecomment-1009135689

Comment: I was going crazy with that 'terms[i:]', thanks!

Comment: I think the `terms[i+1:]` part is an optimization. But the actual bug is with the `yield` statement using the same variable name. (I'd actually call this a bug in Python itself, but I digress.)

Comment: Ah, well yes, I noticed that one :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turns out `terms[i+1:]` is actually incorrect; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656700/936310 for the final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't define an `s`; and you haven't added the formula to it.  The following works for me:

```py
from z3 import *

def block_modelT(s, terms): #I used the name 'block_modelT' so as not to use 'block_model'
    m = s.model()
    s.add(Or([t != m.eval(t) for t in terms]))

def all_smt(s, terms):
    while sat == s.check():
       print(s.model())
       block_modelT(s, terms)

x, y, z = Bools('x y z')
vars = [x,y,z]

phi_0 = x #ignore that I call them phi: it is because I am used to do it like that for predicates (i.e. literals) of other theories: e.g., if x is Int, then phi_0 = (x>0)
phi_1 = y
phi_2 = z

phi = And(phi_0, Or(phi_1, phi_2))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)

all_smt(s, vars)
```

This prints:

```
[z = False, y = True, x = True]
[z = True, x = True]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did define the s but did not include it in the code, since it was in another cell. In any case, this is correct.

Comment: No problem. If you want to avoid z3 giving you partial models, change the last line of your `block_modelT` to read: `s.add(Or([t != m.eval(t, model_completion=True) for t in terms]))`

Comment: Thanks a lot again! The model completion is very useful for me!! Made a last question in EDIT.

Comment: Try: `print(list(all_smt(s, vars)))`

Comment: Got it right! Really curious, since I got the model completion `[[z = False, y = True, x = True], [z = True, y = False, x = True]]` without specifying it like you have just said how to do. Now, I will work on the foundations to understand better why this works and why this is divide and conquer. Thanks very much! By the way, in Collab, `vars` is a reserved word 100%. I do not know why but :(

Comment: The internals of model completion is rather opaque, and its behavior can depend on the version of z3 used. It's always a good idea to specify it; in my opinion. I don't use `Collab`, so not quite sure what else it adds to the ecosystem. It's best to stick to plain python in your questions to keep confusion to a minimum.

Comment: Agree, than you :)