# Some questions about incremental SAT in Z3: can it be deactivated? Which techniques are used inside?

Tags: z3, z3py, theorem-proving, sat, satisfiability

I am still in the process of learning the guts of Z3 (Python).

It was brought to my attention that **Z3 performs incremental SAT solving by default** (see [SAT queries are slowing down in Z3-Python: what about incremental SAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652641/sat-queries-are-slowing-down-in-z3-python-what-about-incremental-sat)): specifically, every time you use the `s.add` command (where `s` is a solver), it means that it adds that clause to `s`, but it does not forget everything you have learned before.

**First question**: can non-incremental SAT solving be done in Z3? That is, somehow 'deactivate' the incremental solving. What would this mean? That we are creating a new solver for each enlarged formula?

For instance, this approach would be Z3-default-incremental:

```
...
  phi = a_formula
  s = Solver()
  s.add(phi)
  while  s.check() == sat: 
    s.check()
    m = s.model()
    phi = add_modelNegation(m)
    s.add(phi) #in order not to explore the same model again
  ...
```

That is, once we get a model, we attach the negated model to the **same** solver.

While this one is 'forcing' Z3 to be non-incremental:

```
...
  phi_st = a_formula
  s = Solver()
  s.add(phi_st)
  negatedModelsStack = []
  while  s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    phi_n = add_modelNegation(m)
    negatedModelsStack.append(phi_n)
    original_plus_negated = And(phi_st, And(negatedModelsStack))
    s = Solver()
    s.add(original_plus_negated) #in order not to explore the same model again
  ...
```

That is, once we get a model, we attach the obtained models to a **new** solver.

Am I right?

On the other hand, in the attached link, the following is stated:

*Compare this to, for instance, CVC4; which is by default not incremental. If you want to use CVC4 in incremental mode, you have to pass a specific command line argument*

Does this mean in CVC4 you must create a new solver every time? Like in the second code?

**Second question**: how can I know exactly what techniques I am using to do incremental solving in Z3? I have been reading about incremental SAT theory and I see that one of those techniques is 'CDCL' ([http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/~audemard/slidesMontpellier2014.pdf](http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/%7Eaudemard/slidesMontpellier2014.pdf)), is this used in Z3's incremental search?

**References:** In order not to inundate Stack with similar questions, which readings do you recommend for incremental SAT in general and Z3's incremental SAT in particular? Also, is the incremental SAT of Z3 similar to the ones of other solvers such as MiniSAT or PySAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to get z3 to act in a non-incremental way. But, if that's your goal, simply do not call `check` more than once: That's equivalent to being non-incremental. (Think of being incremental an "additional feature." You don't have to use it. The only difference between z3 and cvc4 is that the latter requires you to tell it ahead of time that you intend to use it in an incremental fashion, while the former is incremental by default.) As an end user you don't really need to know or care about the difference.

*Side note* If you start cvc4 without telling it to be incremental and call `check` twice, it'll complain. z3 won't. But otherwise the experience should be the same.

I don't think knowing how solvers implement incrementally is really helpful from a programming perspective. (It's of course paramount if you are implementing your own SMT solver.) There are many papers online for many aspects of SMT, though if you want to study the topic from scratch I recommend Daniel and Ofer's book on decision procedures: http://www.decision-procedures.org

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my notion of 'incremental' has been inaccurate: I considered a SAT 'find-all-solutions' search to be non-incremental if for every new model, a new solver (that has, of course, learnt nothing before) was created. Thanks also for the reference: I also recommend that book. However, the focus is not on programming but on theory. Thanks again :)

Comment: There aren't really any "programming" oriented books/resources on SMT, as far as I know. The two that I know are: https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html (referenced before), and https://sat-smt.codes (which is a collection of various examples, with varying styles of presentation). Both can be helpful.